# Servicestack: Is there any way to add key value pair from database in OnConnect server Event

Tags: servicestack

I have the below OnConnect event in the startup file.

I like to add key-value pairs the value I want from the database.
Something like this.

```
OnConnect = (subscription, args) =>
                    {
                       var value = db.Select<Users>(v => v.Id == subscription.UserId).First();
agrs.Add("Key", value);
                    }
```

Comment: Can you make the question clearer on what exactly you're trying to achieve and what's the actual problem that's preventing it.

Comment: Ok, So on the server-side I have an OnConnect event in the startup.cs file, In the args argument of the onConnect  I have to add a new key-value pair but the key-value I want from the database, as it is a dictionary we can directly add key-value pair but how to fetch data from database in OnConnect Event. It will also be okay if we can add a new property in subscription argument.

Comment: I'm trying to workout the specific question you're looking for an answer to, do you just want to know how to resolve the DB from the IOC?

Comment: Yes, And is it good practice to fetch data from the database in the startup file? because I found that there is already a userId key in the args and userId field in the subscription also, So Is there any better way to add another field from the user table in either subscription or args.

Comment: If your App requires data from the DB to configure it, fetching it from the Startup or AppHost.Configure() is as good a place as any, if it's for a user you'd typically populate it on the Users Session when they authenticate which would save you from hitting the DB later. Note: you can use the `OnCreated` callback to access the `IRequest` context + access authenticated Users session with `req.GetSession()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of ServiceStack you can resolve your IOC Dependencies via the `HostContext` and `HostContext.AppHost` singletons, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature {
    OnConnect = (sub, connectArgs) => {
        using var db = HostContext.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open();
    }
});
```